# Ошибка ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '6.56' на python

Tags: python, python-3.x

https://pastebin.com/dkKZx3PS - код

```
import math

from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

init()

print( Fore.BLACK )
print( Back.RED )

print('Добро пожаловать в дебильный калькулятор V5.3!')
print('После вопроса пробелы ставить не нужно, а сразу писать что у Вас спрашивают!')

print( Back.CYAN )

print('+ - сложение')
print('- - вычитание')
print('* - умножение')
print('/ - деление')
print('** - возведение в степень')
print('% - деление по модулю')
print('S - пропустить и перейти к округлению и числу ПИ')
print( Back.GREEN )
what = input( "Что делаем? (+, -, *, /, **, %): " )

print( Back.YELLOW)

if what == "+":
    a = float( input("Введи первое число: ") )
    b = float( input("Введи второе число: ") )
    c = a + b
    print("Результат: " + str(c))

if what == "*":
    a = float( input("Введи первое число: ") )
    b = float( input("Введи второе число: ") )
    c = a * b
    print("Результат: " + str(c))

if what == "/":
    a = float( input("Введи первое число: ") )
    b = float( input("Введи второе число: ") )
    c = a / b
    print("Результат: " + str(c)) 

if what == "**":
    a = float( input("Введи первое число: ") )
    b = float( input("Введи второе число: ") )
    c = a ** b
    print("Результат: " + str(c))

if what == "%":
    a = float( input("Введи первое число: ") )
    b = float( input("Введи второе число: ") )
    c = a % b
    print("Результат: " + str(c))

if what == "-":
    a = float( input("Введи первое число: ") )
    b = float( input("Введи второе число: ") )
    c = a - b
    print("Результат: " + str(c))

print( Back.GREEN )

if what == "S":
    print('1 - обычное округление')
    print('2 - округление к меньшему числу')
    print('3 - округление к большему числу')
    print('4 - число ПИ')
    vibor2 = input('Ваш выбор? (1, 2, 3, 4): ')

    if vibor2 == "1":
        d = input('Число для округления?: ' )
        k = int(d)
        print( 'Результат: ' + round(k) )

    if vibor2 == "2":
        d = input('Число для округления?: ' )
        k = int(d)
        print( 'Результат: ' + math.floor(d) )

    if vibor2 == "3":
        d = input('Число для округления?: ')
        k = int(d)
        print( 'Результат: ' + math.ceil(d) )

    if vibor2 == "4":
        print('Число ПИ: ' + str(math.pi) )
print()
```

[image: Ошибка 1]
[image: Ошибка 2]
[image: Ошибка 3]
Пробовал разные варианты:
Изменял на fload, int, bool.
Потом добавил "k = int(d)" и тоже также изменял. Ошибка просто менялась, но нормально программа не запускалась.
Код оставил с "k = int(d)", но если что уберу.
Не работают только три округления, всё остальное работает.
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо функции `int()` в командах

```
k = int(d)
```

примените функцию `float()`:

```
k = float(d)
```

(как вы это сделали для переменных `a` и `b` выше.)

---

*Обьяснение:*

Не возможно выражением`int(k)` конвертировать строку `k`, когда в ней что-то другое чем целое число (с возможными пробелами перед и за, но нет во внутри числа).

В каких-то других языках это допустимо, но в Питоне нет.

Кроме того, вам все-таки нужно в переменной `k` *десятичное* число, потому что вы *хотите округлить его разными образами* (что для целых чисел даст онин и тот-же результат).

Answer (score 1):

`int('34.4')` не будет работать, потому что нужно делать, например, так: `int(float('34.4'))`

В вашем случае, если вы хотите округлять, то вы делаете, допустим,

```
    if vibor2 == "1":
        d = input('Число для округления?: ' )
        k = float(d)
        print( 'Результат: ' + round(k) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так:

```
import numpy
d = input('Число для округления?: ' ) 
k = numpy.float64(d)
```

Comment: Зачем тут эта тяжелая либа? :)